# Geting data: Complex MySQL query, vs PHP cycles

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, here is my problem.

I have a table, lets call it Mails. The primary key is MailId. Ths table has a on to many relationship with a table Items, which has the primary key ItemId and references the Mail with Items.MailId . And then there is a table called Templates, which has a one to one relationship with the Items, Templates.ItemId=Items.ItemId.

What I want to know, what is the most efficient way to get this data:

MailId --------------------- ItemId[TemplateId], ItemId[TemplateId], ItemId[TemplateId], ItemId [TemplateId]

SO what I'm trying to draw here is a row, where in a table there is a cell with the MailId then a cell, that contains all of the Items referencing this MailId, and each item is a link that either point to the add or edit page, depending on if this item has a template.

**My Solution**

I first fetch all of the Mails, and then run the Array through a `foreach()` loop in PHP, and on every iteration get the ItemId's for this Mail. The query I use to get the ItemId's has a subquery, that counts the references to this Item, and return either a 1 or a 0. It looks something like this:

```
SELECT `Items`.*,`Items`.ItemId as wid,(SELECT 
count(templateId) from `Templates` where ItemId=wid) as
templateCount from `Item` where MailId=$id
```

This works, but I hate using cycles for something, that I think could be done with a query. 
Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can and should do it in one query.

```
SELECT
  Mails.MailId,
  Items.*,
  COUNT(Templates.ItemId)
FROM
  Mails
INNER JOIN
  Items
ON
  Mails.MailId = Items.MailId
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  Templates
ON
  Templates.ItemId = Items.ItemId
GROUP BY
  Mails.MailId, Items.ItemId
ORDER BY
  Mails.MailId, Items.ItemId
```

Your PHP code will be slightly different, since you have only one loop over the rows. You need to look at the MailId to know when to start a new row in your HTML (when the MailId of the current row is different from the last row).

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! P.S. Does it matter in terms of speed how many columns I choose to grab from each table?